# How to confirm only ONE in-app purchase receipt in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

**ios7 method**

```
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = (SKPaymentTransaction *)object;
NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithData:transaction.transactionReceipt];
NSString *encodedString = [receiptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

**ios8 method**

```c
NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptUrl];
NSString *encodedString = [receiptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

When you confirm Recipe with ios8 method itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt respond with all user purchases inside JSON object. 
But if you use ios7 method, itunes will respond exactly for (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction

So, the question is: How to confirm only **one** transaction in iOS8 without deprecated methods?

P.S. I hope iOS8 is so flexible as an iPhone6 (smile)